# system of partial differential equation and boundary condition.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

Let $\Omega$ be a regular domain, for example be a rectangle.

Is it true that solve system of PDE's like this:

$$u+\Delta w=0, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~w=b1,~\frac{\partial w}{\partial n}=b2,~~~\text{on}~
 \partial \Omega $$
$$\Delta u=0,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{with out boundary condition.} $$

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "Is it true that solve system of PDEs like this". Can you clarify?

Comment: I want to solve it numerically, this system needs two  type of boundary conditions. Is it true that the first equation has both boundary conditions and the second does not any boundary condition or I have to derived a boundary condition for the second.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question [as clarified in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698728/system-of-partial-differential-equation-and-boundary-condition?noredirect=1#comment1474122_698728):

Yes, your formulation is fine. (Though numerical stability I know nothing about.)

The idea is the following: just take the Laplacian of the first equation, since we know that $\Delta u = 0$ you get

$$ \Delta\Delta w = 0 $$

which is the biharmonic equation. It is well-known that as a fourth order elliptic operator, this problem on a domain is well-posed when you prescribe **two** boundary conditions. And as you have provided $w|_{\partial\Omega}$ and $\partial_n w|_{\partial\Omega}$ you can convert the problem to a variational formulation and solve. (You would be minimizing the square norm of either the Hessian or Laplacian of $w$ under the boundary constraints.)

After you solve the biharmonic equation for $w$, you can easily recover $u$ as minus the Laplacian of $w$ using your original equation.